# smtp problem in server, cannot find hostname

Tags: php, linux, smtp

I am getting this error when i send email by mail function. (ip and emails were hid)

```
user@server.com R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp defer (-44): SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<user@server.com>: host mail.server.com [XX.XX.XX.XX]: 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname, [XX.XX.XX.XX]
```

any help ?

Thanks

Comment: I came here looking for a solution to my problem, since I found it by myself maybe it may help other people who end up here: http://serverfault.com/a/810101/250506

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check what reverse DNS shows this way:

```
$ dig mail.mydomain.com
...
mail.mydomain.com   90  IN  A   74.125.77.121
```

Reverse lookup

```
$ dig -x 74.125.77.121
...
121.77.125.74.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN    PTR ew-in-f121.1e100.net.
```

So mail.mydomain.com not equal to ew-in-f121.1e100.net - you get blocked.

Comment: mail.mydomain.net.    13865   IN      CNAME   mydomain.net.
mydomain.net.         13767   IN      A       XX.XX.XX.XX

Comment: 132.243.162.178.in-addr.arpa. 99406 IN  PTR     XX.XX.XX.XX.local.

Comment: Contact your ISP. You should have static IP address and ask them to provide reverse lookup entry in their domain. However first level domain local. means that you have your server in LAN. You need to get it to Internet and get public IP address.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the remote server is trying to do a [reverse DNS lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) of your IP address -- this is typically done as an anti-spam measure.  This configuration is the responsibility of the
owner of that block of IP addresses -- in your case, probably the ISP that's hosting your server.